# Put app logo image on ionic header with side menu

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, css-position

I want to put the app logo image on ionic header at center or left with vertical center align but its move to top in header.

Here following code I use to display this but issues get with this

```
<ion-view view-title="<img src='img/logo.png' width="44px" />">
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<ion-nav-title>`
Try this

```
<ion-view>
   <ion-nav-title>
      <img src="img/logo.png">
   </ion-nav-title>
   <ion-content>
       //Your content here
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: its take full height of header bar

Comment: then you have to set some style to image

Comment: change image size..or add !important...you can check from inspect element to see what actually works

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNwaNe    Check this codepen...i have added test as a title using above method

Comment: You want both? image and title?

Comment: Cummon man..working with everything just check new pen with image and text http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNwaNe

Comment: You have to set some style dude...check it now